# Do these inequalities make sense?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, inequality

I have two sets of inequalities and i just want to know if they are correct.

The parameters $\mu, K, d_1, \sigma_1,\sigma_2$ and dependent variables $H,F$are positive. Also $\sigma_2>\sigma_1$.

\begin{align*}
\frac{dH}{dt}&=\mu \frac{(H+F)^2}{K^2+(H+F)^2}-d_1H-H\left(\sigma_1-\frac{\sigma_2 F}{H+F}\right)\\
&\leq \mu-(d_1+\sigma_1-\sigma_2)H\\
&\leq 0 \quad \textrm{if}\quad H\geq \frac{\mu}{d_1+\sigma_1-\sigma_2}
\end{align*}

Also this one:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dF}{dt}&=H\left(\sigma_1-\frac{\sigma_2 F}{H+F}\right)-(p+d_2)F \\
&\leq H\left(\sigma_1-\frac{\sigma_2 F}{H+F}\right)\\
&\leq (\sigma_1-\sigma_2)H\\
&<0 
\end{align*}

Comment: To see the first inequality use that $\frac{a}{a+b}<1$ for $a,b>0.$ with respect to the second one, what assumptions have you on $p,d_2?$

Comment: $p$ and $d_2$ are both positive. So I left them and put a $\leq$ sign. Do the first set of inequalities make sense?

Comment: The first set of inequalities is correct. In the second one, what happens to $a+b$ if $b<0?$ Is it $a+b<b?$ Do you see it?

Comment: By $a$ and $b$ you mean $p$ and $d_2$?

Comment: No, if $p>0,d_2>0,F>0$ then $-(p+d_2)F<0.$ So $\frac{dF}{dt}=\mathrm{something}-(p+d_2)F<\mathrm{something}.$

Comment: Oh, sorry. I could have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: Yes right. That's why I wrote $\frac{dF}{dt}\leq H(\sigma_1-\frac{\sigma_2F}{H+F})$. Further used the fact that $\frac{\sigma_2 HF}{H+F}\leq \sigma_2 H$. Is it right?

Comment: Absolutely correct.

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a quick response and thorough advice! :) I wasn't really confident about what I did!

Comment: To get confidence you need to practice and ask for finding you possibles mistakes. You know a place to do it. You are doing well. You're welcome.